# Issue when new activity is added inside new Package in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am facing issue when I am adding a new package and adding a new Activity inside that new Package. There is no issue if I try to add new activity in root folder. Below is the structure.

[image]

**Error Details**

Package R does not exists

Comment: import R.......

Comment: Please check this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGoG3.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import your_application_package_name.R;
```

Comment: Thank You very much. It was very useful. Just banged on target.